# kubectl cannot exec or logs pod on other node

Tags: kubernetes

v1.8.2,installed by kubeadm

2 node:

```
    NAME                    STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
192-168-99-102.node     Ready     <none>    8h        v1.8.2
192-168-99-108.master   Ready     master    8h        v1.8.2
```

run nginx to test:

```
NAME                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
curl-6896d87888-smvjm   1/1       Running   0          7h        10.244.1.99   192-168-99-102.node
nginx-fbb985966-5jbxd   1/1       Running   0          7h        10.244.1.94   192-168-99-102.node
nginx-fbb985966-8vp9g   1/1       Running   0          8h        10.244.1.93   192-168-99-102.node
nginx-fbb985966-9bqzh   1/1       Running   1          7h        10.244.0.85   192-168-99-108.master
nginx-fbb985966-fd22h   1/1       Running   1          7h        10.244.0.83   192-168-99-108.master
nginx-fbb985966-lmgmf   1/1       Running   0          7h        10.244.1.98   192-168-99-102.node
nginx-fbb985966-lr2rh   1/1       Running   0          7h        10.244.1.96   192-168-99-102.node
nginx-fbb985966-pm2p7   1/1       Running   0          7h        10.244.1.97   192-168-99-102.node
nginx-fbb985966-t6d8b   1/1       Running   0          7h        10.244.1.95   192-168-99-102.node
```

kubectl exec pod on master is OK!

but when i exec pod on other node,return a error:

```
kubectl exec -it nginx-fbb985966-8vp9g bash

error: unable to upgrade connection: pod does not exist
```

Comment: Where do you run `kubectl exec -it nginx-fbb985966-8vp9g bash`?  
On master or on the node?

Comment: on the master run it,tks

Comment: Can you ping 192-168-99-102.node from the master?

Comment: @azalio thank u！its ok，i forget modify the hosts file